# How to insert first element to list?

Tags: javascript

I try to use `appendChild` with `cloneNode` to insert li tags with anchors

```
    let alphabet = document.querySelector('.alphabet');
    let ul = document.createElement("ul");
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let anchor = document.createElement('a');
    ul.className = "alphabet__list";
    alphabet.appendChild(ul);
    let arr_RU = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я'];

    for (i = 0; i < arr_RU.length; i++) {
        li.className = "alphabet__item";
        anchor.href = '#'+arr_RU[i];
        anchor.innerText = arr_RU[i];      
        ul.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
        li.appendChild(anchor);     
 }}
```

[image]

But first `a` tag are not in the list. How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `anchor` to `li` before appending `li` to `ul`

```js
let alphabet = document.querySelector('.alphabet');
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
let li = document.createElement("li");
let anchor = document.createElement('a');
ul.className = "alphabet__list";
alphabet.appendChild(ul);
let arr_RU = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я'];

for (i = 0; i < arr_RU.length; i++) {
  li.className = "alphabet__item";
  anchor.href = '#' + arr_RU[i];
  anchor.innerText = arr_RU[i];
  li.appendChild(anchor);  // changed here
  ul.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<div class='alphabet'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also move the creation of the `a` and `li` elements to inside the loop which would make the code a bit more readable and less error-prone, like so:

```js
let alphabet = document.querySelector(".alphabet");
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.className = "alphabet__list";
alphabet.appendChild(ul);

let arr_RU = [
  "А",
  "Б",
  "В",
  "Г",
  "Д",
  "Е",
  "Ё",
  "Ж",
  "З",
  "И",
  "Й",
  "К",
  "Л",
  "М",
  "Н",
  "О",
  "П",
  "Р",
  "С",
  "Т",
  "У",
  "Ф",
  "Х",
  "Ц",
  "Ч",
  "Ш",
  "Щ",
  "Э",
  "Ю",
  "Я",
];

for (i = 0; i < arr_RU.length; i++) {
  let anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = "#" + arr_RU[i];
  anchor.innerText = arr_RU[i];

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = "alphabet__item";
  li.append(anchor);

  ul.append(li);
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-create the elements on every iteration, no need for `cloneNode()`, and also switch the order of appending. First append the `a` to the `li` then append the `li` to the `ul`.

The problem you are having is that you are first appending an empty `li` **clone** to the `ul`, then you are appending an `a` to the original `li`, which is not the same as the clone you just appended. On the second iteration the original `li` now contains the `a` and you then `clone` it again and append the clone into the `ul`, which is why you don't get a value for the first iteration.

```js
let alphabet = document.querySelector('.alphabet');
let ul = document.createElement("ul");

ul.className = "alphabet__list";
alphabet.appendChild(ul);
let arr_RU = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я'];

for (let i = 0; i < arr_RU.length; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let anchor = document.createElement('a');
  li.className = "alphabet__item";
  anchor.href = '#'+arr_RU[i];
  anchor.innerText = arr_RU[i];
  li.appendChild(anchor);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet"></div>
```